# Resize parent div to fit child div

Tags: html, css, position

This may be a long shot to do without using JavaScript...

If I have the following (stripped out code for the problem)

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

```css
#container {
    position: relative;
}

#content {
    position: absolute;
}
```

The content box contains dynamic content so a fixed height cannot be used.

Position absolute has to be used on the content div as its using jQuery UI stuff...

How would I get the container box to resize its height to fit the content?

I understand this is probably impossible without using some sort of JavaScript, as placing a div positioned absolute takes it out of the flow etc etc, but just wondered if anyone knew of some sort of work around?

Thanks!

Comment: did you try setting the container min-width and min-height properties?

Comment: what's the fear of javascript for?

Comment: What's the reason for using `position:absolute` in the first place?

Comment: Could you elaborate on why "using jQuery UI stuff" means you have to use `position:absolute`? And if you're using jQuery anyway, you know you're already using Javascript, right?

Comment: I have no fear of using JavaScript, just been asked not to, the application itself it quite JavaScript heavy already!

Answer (score 2):

edit: I misunderstood the question the first time.

If all else fails, here's a jQuery solution:

```
$('#container').css('height',$('#content').height());
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have no idea what your content is (jQuery UI stuff).  However, say it's just an image:

```
#container {
    position: relative;
}

#content {
    position: absolute;
    top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0;
}
```

This will set your content area to at least 100% width and height of the parent.

Comment: otherwise jquery is your best bet. you could also look in to css3 background-size

Comment: Please understand, that you just suggested the exact opposite of what OP is trying to accomplish: OP is looking for a (hopefully non JS way) to auto resize the PARENT according to its children. I, however, am looking for the specifically jquery way to do this, since I am having to work within a jquery function that has already decided on length and width, but I moved some stuff around and need it to recalculate the dimensions based on the content children I basically resized.

Comment: Please understand, This answer is from 2012... y you so mad?

Don't tell me your "jquery function" problems.